# TypeError in plugin 'gulp-webp-css'

Tags: gulp

I try to save changes in my code, but I have this issue:

```
[00:49:04] 'html' errored after 43 ms
[00:49:04] TypeError in plugin 'gulp-webp-css'
Message:
    Cannot read property '0' of null
Details:
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
[00:49:04] 'default' errored after 124 ms
```

Here's the link to my gulpfile.js code - https://jsfiddle.net/yLo9b4na/

I tried to look for reasons for several hours, but did not succeed.

Has anyone encountered such a problem? I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it means that you have an `img` tag empty like this:

```
<img src="" />
```

By the way, it will crush webp even if it's commented.